# MVVM Programming

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Hello i've just started using MVVM pattern and i have trouble with the showing of text in the window. can you help me .
This is the model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace trying_the_best.Model
{
    public class PersoanaModel : DependencyObject
    {

        public string Nume
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(NumeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(NumeProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Nume.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty NumeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Nume", typeof(string), typeof(PersoanaModel), new PropertyMetadata(0));



         public string Prenume
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(PrenumeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PrenumeProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Prenume.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PrenumeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Prenume", typeof(string), typeof(PersoanaModel), new PropertyMetadata(0));


    }
}
```

Here is the ViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using trying_the_best.Model;

namespace trying_the_best.ViewModel
{
   public class PersoanaViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<PersoanaModel> persoana
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public void incarcarepersoane()
        {
            ObservableCollection<PersoanaModel> Persoana = new ObservableCollection<PersoanaModel>();
            Persoana.Add(new PersoanaModel { Nume = "Bogdan", Prenume = "Marius" });

            persoana = Persoana;
        }

    }
}
```

and here is the mainView

```
<Window x:Class="trying_the_best.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:trying_the_best.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="89,40,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding XPath=Nume}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="219" Height="50"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

With the cs file

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using trying_the_best.ViewModel;
namespace trying_the_best
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

i am trying to make that name to show.Can you give me an advice ? i have searched some answers on the internet but i could find a fix for my problem maybe i am just a noob but yea i need help

Comment: In this code the DataContext of the view is not set and there is no instance of the ViewModel.

Comment: You need to start small then work big.  You've started big and now you can't see the needle for the haystack.

Comment: Dependency Properties in the model seems a little odd. Are you sure you actually need them?  Usually the model just has "normal" properties on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues in your code

**First of all**, your view-model contains a list of persons. As far as I can tell from your view, you want to display *one* person, right?

**Furthermore** the `DataContext` of your view does not seem to be set. To access fields of your view-model, you'll have to set the `DataContext`.

```
<Window x:Class="trying_the_best.MainWindow"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Your.Namespace.Here; assembly=Your.Assembly"
        [...]>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:PersoanaViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    [...]
</Window>
```

I've elided the irrelevant parts.

**Third thing** I've noticed is, that you access your model directly. You should avoid this. Set the `Persoana` in your view-model and create properties to access the values

```
class PersoanaViewModel
{
    private Persoana _persoana;

    public string Nume
    {
        get
        {
            return _persoana.Nume;
        }
        set
        {
            _persoana.Nume = value;
        }
    }
    [...]
}
```

Basically it should work now, **but** if you are changing the model in your view-model *after* constructor you will notice that your view is not updated. To achieve the view being updated, you'll have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your view-model

```
class PersoanaViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    [...]

    public Persoana Persoana 
    {
        get
        {
            return _persoana;
        }
        set
        {
            if(value == _persoana) return; // do not update if the objects are equal
            _persoana = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Nume));
        }
    }
}
```

This should - basically - work, but it's only meant to be an example that shows you how it *can* be done. There are some more things to consider in the real world.

Comment: oke made the necesarry changes but doesn't show anything still

Comment: Hm, could you create an empty constructor for PersoanaViewModel, start the debugger and check if this constructor is called - just set a breakpoint in the constructor. Furthermore, are you sure about `{Binding XPath=Nume}` shouldn't it be `{Binding Path=Nume}` or, even simpler, `{Binding Nume}`?

Comment: `<PersoanaViewModel />` won't work, needs the correct namespace definition applied.